# Google Analytic Page View with Modal/Overlay Ajax Content

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, google-analytics

I am setting up a WordPress tool where the user clicks a link, and a single post is pulled from the database and inserted into a modal/overlay. (exactly like http://www.usatoday.com/)

Now, since the user is not visiting the actual page, I am assuming there is no way to track it as a "page view" to get the "time spent on page" and other important page-related stats.

I do know that I can track the URL event, but just tracking the URL click is not enough.

Is there a way to achieve tracking the modal content as a page view for the actual post URL pulled into the modal? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but not easy to answer without seeing the code that calls your overlay.

Basically you would look if your modal function provides a callback (a javascript function that is run after the code has executed) and provide a "virtual pageview", i.e. run a pageview call and pass in a custom path that indicates the modal window:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/modal/path/to/post/');
```

The path you provided as extra parameter will appear in your content reports as a page. If you also want to provide a title (or override any other [field](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference) in GA) you can pass a JSON object as third parameter:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
    page:'/modal/path/to/post/', 
    title:'my title' 
});
```

Since this is tagged ajax - you can put the pageview into the callback for the ajax success event so it will be fired only when the page is actually loaded.

Comment: That makes sense. The AJAX will just be pulling in the post content into the modal. So if we ignore the AJAX, can the simplest implementation be as simple as generating the links like:
<a href=”post-permalink” onClick=”ga(‘send’, ‘pageview’, ‘/post-permalink/’);”> </a>

Comment: Sure. Putting this in the ajax success callback would make sure that this fires only when the ajax call completes, but for all practical purposes puttin this in the onclick event will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function for all modals and pass it along when you need it.

```
function trackModals(path) {
    ga('send', 'pageview', '/modal' + path);
}
```

Then, you can call it with:

```
trackmodals('/register/');
```

You can reuse it if you verify which modal they are on with if, switch and etc statements.